# Angular2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in Angular, so I choose Angular2.

I was following official guide [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html)

Here is code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.34/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var AppComponent = ng
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app'
    })
    .View({
      template: '<h1 id="output">My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function () { }
    });
```

Then I type `live-server --port=8000`, but it display nothing.

Comment: Have you check browser console?

Comment: "Install node and npm first if you haven't already. They're indispensible front-end developer tools."

Comment: Keep in mind: "Angular 2 is currently in Developer Preview. We recommend using Angular 1.X for production applications".

Comment: Try to create a Plunker  where you can get Some Helping hands

Comment: They provide a self-executing bundle? Cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if DOM is ready with `DOMContentLoaded` first and then Bootstrap the app.
Official Angular 2.0 has mentioned to bootstrap.

Also as Jorg said:

> "Angular 2 is currently in Developer Preview. We recommend using Angular 1.X for production applications"

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.37/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript (ES5):

```
var AppComponent = ng
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app'
    })
    .View({
      template: '<h1 id="output">My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function () { }
    });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M36vPVh3WmnPwSyB0lPv?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly, thanks. I guess I should use Angular1.x to finish my product. It seems like 2.0 is unsuitable for me as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

can you add `ng.bootstrap(AppComponent, []);` to the bottom on app.js and update your angular version to
`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.37/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah, I have the same result with Vicky. `DOMContentLoaded` fix it.